# i want Web crawling from ajax(python)

Tags: python

how can i get text in url https://pub.insure.or.kr/compareDis/variableInsrn/fundDay/fundAssetAjax.do ??
i can see only title.

i want to crwaling in [자산구성내역] - [자산비중] table

Here is my python code:

```html
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://pub.insure.or.kr/compareDis/variableInsrn/fundDay/fundInfoViewPopup.do?stdYmd=20191125&memberCd=L71&fundCd=KLVL71FD25O'

html = urlopen(url).read()
html = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = html.find_all('a')
print(data)
```

Comment: where is your code? What module(s) do you use ? If page uses JavaScript then you will need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: sry i added my code

Comment: This AJAX sends to `fundAssetAjax.do` `POST` requests with some arguments, headers and cookies - and you would have to do the same. It is easier with module `requests` instead of `urllib`

Answer (score 0):

`AJAX` sends to `fundAssetAjax.do` `POST` requests with some arguments, headers and cookies - and you have to do the same. It is easier with module `requests`

I uses `Session()` to get and keep `cookies` so I don't have to do it manually.

Because it had problem with SSL so I use `verify=False`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pub.insure.or.kr/compareDis/variableInsrn/fundDay/fundInfoViewPopup.do?stdYmd=20191125&memberCd=L71&fundCd=KLVL71FD25O'

s = requests.Session() # to keep cookies
r = s.get(url, verify=False) 

params = {
    "fundTabId": "fundSummary",
    "stdYmd": "20191125",
    "memberCd": "L71",
    "fundCd": "KLVL71FD25O"
}

url = 'https://pub.insure.or.kr/compareDis/variableInsrn/fundDay/fundSummaryAjax.do'
r = s.post(url, data=params, verify=False)

#print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_h3 = soup.find_all('h3')
for item in all_h3:
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
펀드보수 및 비용정보(%)
기준가격정보
펀드운용정보
투자목적
공시사항
```

I found params using `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` but it seems there are the same as in url - `fundInfoViewPopup.do?stdYmd=20191125&memberCd=L71&fundCd=KLVL71FD25O`

Comment: Thank you. your comment very helpful! have a nice day :)